# Meaning of -fold

Tags: terminology, cluster-analysis, machine-learning

I saw this text while reading wikipedia(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B)

> The authors tested their method with real and synthetic datasets and obtained typically 2-fold improvements in speed, and for certain datasets close to 1000-fold improvements in error.

and I'm curious about the meaning of -fold, like 1000-fold, 2-fold. 
Is this a kind of unit? or something?
Can anyone give me some references about this term?

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, guys ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twice as large/great/many/etc. A clear method of saying 'I increased the speed by two fold' would be 'I doubled the speed'

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially a multiplier. Read it as 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

It just means "multiple" - so 2-fold is twice as fast and 1000-fold is 1000 times as fast...